# Where does Elastic Beanstalk store my Django app's files?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My static files aren't being found on my EB site. It worked just fine in my local virtualenv, but when I pushed them up to Elastic Beanstalk the static files aren't found.

I'm trying to do some digging into my Elastic Beanstalk's EC2 Instance to find where my Django app's files are, and hopefully from there I can find out why my static files aren't loading.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 17):

In Amazon Linux, I see my Python app's files in `/opt/python/current/app`. This is under Apache using WSGI; I figured it out by looking at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf`.

`$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-45-93-242 4.4.15-25.57.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 27 22:37:49 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out by using the following command:

```
sudo find -iname "django"
```

It pointed me to the following path:

```
/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django
```

It seems like that's where your django files should live, at least on Ubuntu 14.04. I also figured out that for some reason my static files didn't get uploaded at all, so I'm still working on that.

I want to point out that this should work for any Elastic Beanstalk app, regardless of whetehr it's Django or Ruby on Rails or whatever - the sudo find -iname command is super useful.